# Time is what keeps everything from appearing at once

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time

This is a question about time.

In this talk http://ed.ted.com/lessons/einstein-s-brilliant-mistake-entangled-states-chad-orzel Chad Orzel makes the point that if the *same* quantum experiment is repeated as a series, the *same result* is produced but if the same experiment is now interrupted by another experiment, testing for a different attribute, a new outcome is possible. Interruption resets the clock.Staying with that....

Quantum mechanics is silent about time, a history or the sense of "before" or "after" is a personal subjective experience that has led some to say that the idea of time is created to keep everything from appearing to happen at once. Even the Quantum Zeno Effect points to the subjectivity of time. So my question(s)..

Does anyone know the name of the experience of the same outcome *if* the series of experiments is repeated without change *and* without interruption?
And doesnt this point to the mind creating the sense of time to keep events apart, so a series of such identical and uninterrupted experiments counts as a single event, or single unit of "time"?

Comment: You can't do an experiment that leaves a system 'without change and without interruption', since doing the experiment (performing a measurement) IS the interruption. There are so called weak measurements which are being worked on but these still affect the system to some degree.

Comment: Remco: I can't answer your question, but check out [reproducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility). And I'm afraid to say you seemed to have picked up a bit of "quantum woo" here. The mind doesn't create time to keep events apart. Just take a look at what a clock does. It features some kind of regular cyclical motion that is counted or geared down to show some cumulative display that you call _the time_. Time is just some cumulative measure of motion. Or events if you prefer. If there is no motion there are no events, and then there is no time.

Comment: John:John Wheeler (delayed choice expt. architect) said “Time is just a construct of the universe to keep everything from happening all at once.” Emanuel Kant called time a “natural assumption” encapsulated in language to be real.It seems physics remains in the inertia of Greek objective thinking as Schrodinger pointed out.Time is what clocks measure, yes, but that reproducibility expt. (thank you) allows time to remain a Kantian concept.Einstein incorporated time in spacetime, it is also dead space, nothing happens.The perception of time seems just a shift in perspective and epiphenomenal.

Comment: Akoben, are you therefore disagreeing with Chad Orzel? His observation about reproducibility is quite stunning.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum mechanics is not silent about time, instead it specifically says exactly how states evolve in time.

There are some interactions that change things to a fixed set of final states. So in general they do change an arbitrary state.
But some of those interactions have a consistency that if something was already in one those fixed states that can be produced as a final state, that the interaction doesn't change it.

Its like it forces the state into the closest one the accepted final states.  So if you do them twice in a row you get consistent results. We call these interactions observation or measurements not because those are good words but because those are the closest we have to measurements or observation are interactions that at least are consistent.

If you do one of those interactions and then wait, then things are going to change. If you do one of them and then do a different ones things Ade going to change.

Doing things that change things results in things changing.

The Quantum Zeno effect is just the fact that these kinds of interactions force things to the closest acceptable state so if they can do that faster and better and quicker than other things try to change those states then if you do that interaction enough it wins.

It's about as deep as noting that if you make a mess faster than someone cleans then your place will be a mess. Not deep at all.

There is no fancy name for the fact that an interaction that doesn't change a certain state will not change that state. And waiting is just letting it interact with its environment. So that's why pausing and waiting matters.